# Creating a measure using DAX function Left on a table from Azure Analysis service

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get the first 4 digits from a string from a table in Power BI. The connection is a live connection / Direct which does not allow me to edit the query. Also, I am unable to create a new column. So I have to stick with creating a new Measure.

[image: Live Connection]

[image: Only Measure Available]

Now, I am using the following formula to get what I need.

```
LocationCd = mid(vw_DW_Contracts[ContractNumber],1,5)
```

but, this is not working a the vw_DW_Contracts table cannot be used in a measure. Is there a workaround to such problem?

I do not have access to the analysis service so cannot make any modifications in the source.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but, this is not working a the vw_DW_Contracts table cannot be used in a measure.

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but I'm guessing the message you see is telling you that measures expect an aggregation. The formula you posted would be great as a calculated column where it can be evaluated row by row. Measures are aggregations over multiple rows.

If you are trying to make a new field that is the location code that can be used in visuals on a categorical axis, this should be a column rather than a measure. You could write a measure to show a location cd using something like `LASTNONBLANK (mid(vw_DW_Contracts[ContractNumber],1,5), 1)` but I doubt that is what you want.